# How to let selector that socketchannel key change in java nio

Tags: java, queue, nio

I have question on usage java nio and hope someone who has a lot of java nio knowledge can help me to clarify some misconcept.

I am using java nio socket. It is possible that the write buffer is filled up using socketchannel.write(). In this case, the remaining buffer is queued and key is changed to OP_WRITE. One of my scenario is that the queue length is pretty long. Each time before call selector.select(),I change key to OP_WRITE from another queue called pendingRequest. But I find since the read is pretty slow, after the sending processing finshes, there are many messages unwritten and they are still in the queue. How to handle this problem?

In my code, I have two writing place. One is from generator: when it has message to publish, it write to channel directly. If buffer is full, the data will be queued. A second place is in dispatcher: when key is writable, it call back write() to write the queued data. I guess the two parts can compete for the write. I just feel that my code lack some handling  to cooperate two writes.

Is there any solution to solve my problem presented above? I find in my code many queued data cannot be written out. When the key is writable, the generator may write data again, which cause the queued data has less change to be written out. How to make this part right? Thanks

// In WriteListener(), the writing code are the following three parts

```
   public synchronized int writeData(EventObject source) {      
    int n = 0; 
    int count = 0;

    SocketChannel socket = (SocketChannel)source.getSource();       
    ByteBuffer buffer = ((WriteEvent)source).getBuffer();   
    try {
        write(socket);
    } catch (IOException e1) {          
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       

    while (buffer.position()>0) {   
        try {           
                buffer.flip();  
                n = socket.write(buffer);                                   
                if(n == 0) {
                        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);                         synchronized (this.pendingData) {  
                            List<ByteBuffer> queue = (List<ByteBuffer>) this.pendingData.get(socket); 
                            if(queue == null) {
                                queue = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
                                this.pendingData.put(socket, queue); 
                        }
                        queue.add(buffer);

                        logger.logInfo("queue length:" + queue.size());
                    }                                               
                    break;
                }               
                count += n; 

        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {                       
            buffer.compact();              
        }
    }   

    if(buffer.position()==0) {                      
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);                  
    }
            return count;   

}
```

// ==== This write method is used to write queued buffer

```
  public synchronized int write(SocketChannel sc, ByteBuffer wbuf) {        
    int n = 0; 
    int count = 0;

    SelectionKey key = sc.keyFor(this.dispatcher.getDemultiplexer().getDemux());                
    while (wbuf.position()>0) {     
        try {           
            wbuf.flip();        

            n = sc.write(wbuf);             

            if(n == 0) {    
                   key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);                                  
                    synchronized (this.pendingData) {  
                        List<ByteBuffer> queue = (List<ByteBuffer>) this.pendingData.get(sc); 
                        if(queue == null) {
                                queue = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
                                this.pendingData.put(sc, queue); 
                        }
                        queue.add(wbuf);
                    }

                    break;
                }               
                count += n; 

        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {               

            wbuf.compact();                
        }
    }   

    if(wbuf.position()==0) {    
        wbuf.clear();               
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);          
    }

return n;       
}
```

// ====This method is a callback of Dispatch when key.isWritable() is true

```
public void write(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {         
   SelectionKey key = socketChannel.keyFor(this.dispatcher.getDemultiplexer().getDemux());     
    synchronized (this.pendingData) {             
        List<ByteBuffer> queue = (List<ByteBuffer>) this.pendingData.get(socketChannel);              
        if(queue == null || queue.isEmpty()) {                 
            // We wrote away all data, so we're no longer interested                 
            // in writing on this socket. Switch back to waiting for  data.                 
            try {                     
                if (key!=null)                         
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);                 
            } catch(Exception ex) {                     
                if (key!=null)                         
                    key.cancel();                 
                }             
        }           

        // Write until there's not more data ...    
        int n = 0;
        while (queue != null && !queue.isEmpty()) {                 
            ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) queue.get(0);   
            // zero length write, break the loop and wait for next writable time 
            n = write(socketChannel, buf);

            logger.logInfo("queue length:" + queue.size() + " used time: " + (t2-t1) + " ms.");

            if(n==0)  {             
                break;
            }
                      queue.remove(0); 

        }        

 }
```

Comment: Please post some code (preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  ) demonstrating the problem you are having.

Comment: The final method, the one that writes the queue, always removes the buffer from the queue even `if (n == 0)`. You should do that test and break *before* removing the buffer, and in fact you should only remove the buffer if it is empty. At the moment you are losing data.

Comment: In my current code, remove (0) is put after test the numbr of bytes written. Currently the code works but the performance is not as good as it should do. How long it takes for the next writable time after the buffer is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a consumer which is too slow, the only option may be to disconnect them to protect your server.  You don't want one bad consumer impacting your other clients.

I usually increase the send buffer size to the point where if it fills, I close the connection. This avoid the complexity of handing unwritten data in Java code because all you are really doing is extending the buffer a little bit more. If you increase the send buffer size, you are doing this transparently. It is possible you don't even need to play with the send buffer size, the default is usually about 64 KB.

Comment: I use the followings to change the socketchannel buffersize. But why serverSocket only can set receivebuffer size.
 socket.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(256 * 1024); socket.socket().setSendBufferSize(256 * 1024);

Comment: @susan ServerSocket lets you change the receive buffer size, which is inherited by accepted sockets, so you can set them to > 64k. If you try to do that to the accepted socket it will fail because > 64k needs the TCP 'window scaling' option which is negotiated during the connect handshake. For the same reason if you want to set a receive buffer > 64k on a client socket you have to do it before connecting it. You can set the send buffer any time as it doesn't require help from the protocol.

Comment: @susan correction: it won't 'fail' but the part above 64k won't be used unless the size is set before the connection.

Comment: Is there any solution to solve my problem presented above? I find in my code many queued data cannot be written out. When the key is writable, the generator may write data again, which cause the queued data has less change to be written out. How to make this part right? Thanks.

Comment: Another reason for suggestion you change the send buffer size is the assumption you have less control over the consumer, which is why it is not performing fast enough to consume the data you are sending it. The "solution" I have is to; log a warning and close the connection to a slow consumer. The reason for potentially increasing the sender buffer is to reduce false negatives i.e. so this doesn't happen unless there is something really wrong.

Comment: I appreciate yor help very much. It works by letting the message written out before generating next message at the generator side. But for the other process, if the buffer is full, wait unitl there is room to write again.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to make sure that new data gets enqueued after data that is already pending to be written.
2. If the behaviour persists, you really only have two choices: either disconnect the client on the grounds of misbehaviour, or stop producing output for it until the backlog clears. Probably both.

You can implement the first via adroit use of a longish select() timeout. If select() returns zero, it means either there are no registered channels or nothing whatsoever has happened to any of them during the timeout period, in which case you might want to think about disconnecting from *all* clients. If you have a lot of concurrent clients that gets too hamfisted to work, so you would have to keep track of the last time each channel got selected, and disconnect any channel whose last activity time gets too long ago.

Within that timeout period you may *also* want to stop producing output for that guy while he is slow reading.

The precise definition of 'longish' is left as an exercise for the reader, but ten minutes comes to mind as a first approximation.

Comment: I appreciate yor help very much. It works by letting the message written out before generating next message at the generator side. But for the other process, if the buffer is full, wait unitl there is room to write again.